# Locate customer by custom attribute in Magento

Tags: magento

I have a custom attribute called rms_id. It's a unique account number that's associated with our customers in another database. I need a way to lookup the customer by this id, without hitting the database manually.

As of now, I can load the customer by email address like so:

```
$customer->loadByEmail($data['email']);
```

This is great, however the email is not always available. The RMS id is. Is there any way to load a user by the custom attribute?

In theory, the following would work:

```
$customer->loadByRmsId($data['account_id']);
```

However it errors out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a good example of this in the core; see [`Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract::loadByAttribute()`[link]](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Abstract.php#L224). It involves using a data model to retrieve a collection, joining the attribute in, and filtering by that attribute. This is necessary if the attribute is not static i.e. not a part of the entity table.

```
$result = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
              ->getCollection()
              ->addAttributeToSelect('rms_‌​id')
              ->addAttributeToFilter('rms_id',{Val})->load();

if (is_object($result)) {
    /* Logic */
}
```

Comment: To actually get the customer (in case you have a unique value and so just filter out one) you can add `->getFirstItem()` after the `->load()`.

Answer (score 1):

but in practice you have to come up with your own method similar to `loadByEmail()` in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php`

or get the e-mail from collection

```
Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('rms_id', 'youremailhere')->load();
```

Comment: Worked for me. Working for custom model/table as well. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
$customer->load($data['account_id'], 'rms_id');
```

Comment: Will this load if the attribute type is not static?

Comment: @benmarks i tried it, it does not work if the attribute is not static.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it also like that:

`$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('rms_id', $data['account_id'])
                ->getFirstItem();`

Will return `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` object.